# Why does my Next.js page not load data on the first load and throw a "FirebaseError: Invalid document reference" error?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, react-hooks, next-auth

I'm using nextauth to log the accounts/sessions of users signing up to my platform. I've got a user dashboard under the below app\user[id]\page.js, where Id is the doc.id logged from nextauth onto firestore using the firestoreAdapter in my [...nextauth] API file.

```js
"use client";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { db } from "@/lib/firebaseConfig";
import { getDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore";

function User() {
  const pathname = window?.location.pathname;
  const userId = pathname.substring(6);
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUser = async () => {
      const docRef = doc(db, "users", userId);
      const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
      if (docSnap.exists()) {
        setUser(docSnap.data());
      } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
    };
    getUser();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-white">{userId}</h1>
      <img src={user.image} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default User;
```

My intention is to fetch the above data as soon as the page loads. Right now, the data loads only if I reload the page, and not on the first load.

On the terminal, I get the below error:

```js
error - app\user\[id]\page.js (7:19) @ window
error - ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at User (./app/user/[id]/page.js:16:22)
   5 | 
   6 | function User() {
>  7 |   const pathname = window?.location.pathname;
     |                   ^
```

And in the browser, I get the below error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
FirebaseError: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but users has 1.
```

I think the problem is because the useEffect kicks in before the client renders. Newbie question, but how do I get the useEffect to only kick in once pathname's value is not undefined?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed thanks to ChatGPT below:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { db } from "@/lib/firebaseConfig";
import { getDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore";

function User() {
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState(null);
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const pathname = window?.location.pathname;
    if (pathname) {
      setUserId(pathname.substring(6));
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userId) {
      const getUser = async () => {
        const docRef = doc(db, "users", userId);
        const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
        if (docSnap.exists()) {
          setUser(docSnap.data());
        } else {
          console.log("No such document!");
        }
      };
      getUser();
    }
  }, [userId]);

  return (
    <div>
      {userId && (
        <>
          <h1 className="text-white">{userId}</h1>
          <img src={user.image} />
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default User;
```

To fix the error, I made sure that the window object is only accessed in the browser and not during server-side rendering. I did this by wrapping the code that accesses the window object inside a check for typeof window !== "undefined".

I separated the code that sets the user ID from the code that fetches the user data. I used two useEffect hooks to accomplish this. The first one runs only on the client-side and sets the user ID by checking the window object. The second one runs only when the user ID changes and fetches the user data from Firestore.

With these changes, the component should render without any errors, and the user data should be fetched as soon as the user ID is available.